# VBA Excel two columns dependency based on the value of 1st column

Tags: excel, vba

I have two values in the same row. These values will be added to other rows below on the same basis.
I would like to make the value from column Q dependent on the value in column P. They both use data validated as a list of values prepared.
The dependency I would like to have is shown in the image below:

[image]

So far I tried to make it by the following code:

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


  Dim RowTarget As Range
  Dim CurrentRow As Long

  Dim cw As Worksheet
  cw = ActiveSheet

  Dim ApprovalStatus As String, RequestStatus As String

  CurrentRow = RowTarget.Row

  ApprovalStatus = cw.Range("P" & CurrentRow)

  RequestStatus = cw.Range("Q" & CurrentRow)

  Select Case ApprovalStatus.Value
  Case "APPROVED"
  RequestStatus.Value = "ACTIVE"
  Case "REJECTED"
  RequestedStatus.Value = "ABORTED"
  Case "SENT FOR APPROVAL"
  RequestedStatus.Value = "ON HOLD"
  Case "N/A"
  RequestedStatus.Value = "COMPLETED"
  End Select


  End Sub
```

At the line of:

```
    Select Case ApprovalStatus.Value
```

I have an error: Invalid qualifier

How could I make the 2nd value dependent on the first one?

Comment: `Worksheet_SelectionChange` fires when a range is selected - you want `Worksheet_Change` and you need to use the `Target` parameter.  Plenty of examples here on SO.

Comment: Also `CurrentRow = RowTarget.Row` you haven't assigned `RowTarget`

Comment: @TimWilliams I can't use Target, because it has been used in different macro.

Comment: @Geographos *I can't use Target, because it has been used in different macro* Then don't declare it as a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use Target, because it has been used in different macro

- `Target` is a parameter variable in `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. It doesn't conflict with other sub procedures.
- You can change the parameter variable name as needed.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal MyTarget As Range)
    Debug.Print MyTarget.Address
End Sub
```

---

- Your code could be as below.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal RowTarget As Range)
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    Dim ApprovalStatus As String 
    Dim RequestStatus As Range
    CurrentRow = RowTarget.Row
    ApprovalStatus = me.Range("P" & CurrentRow).Value
    Set RequestStatus = me.Range("Q" & CurrentRow)
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' You may need this line if Change event is used
    Select Case ApprovalStatus
    Case "APPROVED"
        RequestStatus.Value = "ACTIVE"
    Case "REJECTED"
        RequestedStatus.Value = "ABORTED"
    Case "SENT FOR APPROVAL"
        RequestedStatus.Value = "ON HOLD"
    Case "N/A"
        RequestedStatus.Value = "COMPLETED"
    End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: CurrentRow = RowTarget.Row - getting an error: "Object required!"

Comment: I've test the code w/o issues. How do you use the code?

Comment: Just trying to select some value from P column. Any time I click I get "Object required" error

Comment: OK, I found it. Instead of (ByVal RowTarget As Range) I used (ByVal Target As Range) that was the case! Now it seems to work, but the change appeared just once despite clicking several times. Is it something I could fix here?

Comment: What does `clicking several times` mean?